# How to add an image into Liferay 7 Control Menu

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am working on Liferay 7 and want to add an image in the centre of the Control Menu. How can this be done?

I have followed the steps mentioned over the official website on how to customise the Control Menu.
Few specific questions I have are:

1. Is there a defined template of JSP file that needs to be used?
2. Is there a defined name of the JSP file that needs to be used?

The code I am using is:

```
package portlet;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.GenericArrayType;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import com.liferay.product.navigation.control.menu.BaseJSPProductNavigationControlMenuEntry;
import com.liferay.product.navigation.control.menu.BaseProductNavigationControlMenuEntry;
import com.liferay.product.navigation.control.menu.ProductNavigationControlMenuEntry;
import com.liferay.product.navigation.control.menu.constants.ProductNavigationControlMenuCategoryKeys;

@Component(
    immediate = true,
    property = {
        "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
        "product.navigation.control.menu.category.key=" + ProductNavigationControlMenuCategoryKeys.TOOLS,
        "product.navigation.control.menu.category.order:Integer=19",
        "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
        "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user",
        "javax.portlet.display-name=Customproductnavigationcontrolmenuentry Portlet"
    },
    service = ProductNavigationControlMenuEntry.class
)
public class CustomproductnavigationcontrolmenuentryPortlet extends BaseJSPProductNavigationControlMenuEntry implements ProductNavigationControlMenuEntry  {

    @Override
    public boolean includeIcon(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RequestDispatcher requestdispacher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
        try{
        requestdispacher.include(request, response);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean includeBody(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RequestDispatcher requestdispacher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
        try{
        requestdispacher.include(request, response);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String getIconJspPath() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And on deploying this on the server, I get the following error:

```
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-10][IncludeTag:128] Current URL /web/guest generates exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.liferay.product.navigation.control.menu.BaseJSPProductNavigationControlMenuEntry.include(BaseJSPProductNavigationControlMenuEntry.java:84)
at com.liferay.product.navigation.control.menu.BaseJSPProductNavigationControlMenuEntry.includeIcon(BaseJSPProductNavigationControlMenuEntry.java:68)
at org.apache.jsp.control_005fmen.....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "centre of the Control Menu"?

Comment: The TOOLS area of the control menu, as explained over here- https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/customizing-the-control-menu

Comment: So have you tried as explained in the documentation? Is it not working or is there something you don't understand?

Comment: Followed the documentation but seems like some items are not listed clearly or we might be missing a step or 2. We followed the steps listed but there is no effect of JSP that gets rendered. Initially we were getting issues related to JSP not getting found.

Comment: Is [this your thread](https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/88099016)? If so: Why didn't you tell us. If no: There's information. In any case, the one line description you post here is just not enough to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Yes, that thread on Liferay Forums was created by me. I was just posting questions here to reach more Liferay developers.
I have added details related to the code over the forum thread.